# Python: generate random numbers that follow a trendline

Tags: python, random, statistics, scatter-plot, trendline

I need to make a graphical abstract and I'd like to show the project aim is to predict a positive relationship between two parameters. I don't want to just grab photos off Google like [this](https://thomaselove.github.io/431notes-2017/431-notes_files/figure-html/nyfs1_scatter_bmi_by_waist1-fig-1.png). Can I generate some random points in Python that follow a certain trendline?

Comment: How about taking a linear trend and adding a random noise value?

Comment: Do you have data points, or a formula?

Answer (score 0):

If you have data points, then fit a *regression model* to the data, then add "noise" to the model in the manner the model calls for, to represent the error in the model.  For example, a linear regression model contains an error term at the end that is a normally distributed number (`x ~ N(0, err)`, where the standard deviation `err` is the mean squared error).  Other regression models may have different error terms in the form of random numbers.